Overleaf Drop Shadow Bug on Duplicated Projects
We recently stumbled upon a very obscure bug. When duplicating a beamer project, the drop shadows are suddenly solid black and in some cases in the foreground making the text illegible.


The bug occurs

in Safari
when duplicating a project from the menu
when creating an empty project and copying the code from a different project.

The bug does not occur when a beamer template link is used to create a project, even if the code from the old project is copied in afterwards.
A minimal demo causing the which caused the bug can be found here:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{default}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}

\begin{block}{Remark}
Sample text
\end{block}

\begin{alertblock}{Important theorem}
Sample text in red box
\end{alertblock}

\begin{examples}
Sample text in green box. The title of the block is ``Examples".
\end{examples}
\end{frame}


\end{document}

Any ideas what could be causing this issue are highly appreciated. If anyone thinks this is a bug and knows how to make the Overleaf development team aware of this, feel free to do so.

Welcome to TeX.SE. Since this issue would appear to be specific to the Overleaf's LaTeX platform, have you considered contacting the Overleaf helpdesk directly? Their LaTeX support staff are top-notch.

have you checked whether the engine and version of texlive is the same in the problematic and non-problematic cases? make sure they are all using the same engine and version as a working case. does the downloaded pdf also exhibit the issue? or does it only appear in safari's builtin viewer?

when you copy an overleaf  project it defaults to the latest version (currently texlive 2024) but your old project may have been an older texlive, check the side menu
