Unexpected black areas when using pgfpages and \useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}
Info: beamer v3.71, pgf v3.1.10, TeX Live 2024
% compiled under xelatex
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{theorem}
    this is a theorem
  \end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{definition}
    this is a definition
  \end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

The above MWE produces unexpected black areas around the block environments. I'm not sure this kind of phenomenon has been reported before. What's the reason behind this and how to resolve? :-(
PS: This phenomenon also exists when using the Madrid and Boadilla beamer theme since they invoke \useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded} internally.
PS: With lualatex and pdflatex, the result looks fine.


Similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/729084/47927 ? I’d suspect this to be an issue with the engine or viewer. Mind to show the first few lines of your log?

Works fine for me. Which viewer do you use?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I use skim

@Stephen Works fine in skim as well https://i.sstatic.net/f5KrlMP6.png Is your viewer up-to-date?

And please also add how you are compiling your document

Don't use xelatex with beamer. It causes a lot of problems. It can make text on note pages disappear, cause an incorrect sequence of uncovering content etc.

What a disappointing limitation! I've been using xetex for a long time.

And why is this information not mentioned in the beamer manual?

@Stephen I'll see if I can find a good place to add a note in the manual

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I suggest adding the note at the first item of the section 1.1 in the manual.

@Stephen Note added: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/dc0cae2b34d752b9c84af69dba4a95736309bafc Now have fun with lualatex (or whatever else you now use instead of xelatex) :P

XeLaTeX isn't a good choice for beamer documents(*).
Besides the problem you noticed it can also cause

missing text on note pages
incorrect uncovering of overlays, see e.g. Using transparent pauses in lstlisting using XeLaTex (beamer)
incorrect spacing in equations, see e.g. Beamer renders equations differently

You could switch to pdflatex or lualatex to avoid such problems.

(*) or documents in general, see e.g. https://www.texdev.net/2024/11/05/engine-news-from-the-latex-project
